# How can I make a PDF output file form Excel in Vba access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, pdf

I used to print Excel file in Vba Access by this code :

`Excel_App.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True`

How can I make a PDF from Excel file in Vba Access?

Comment: please indent the line of code by 4 spaces so that it shows up as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this method..

**Example**-

```
Private Sub Prepare_PDF_Click()
Dim MyFullName As String
Dim xlAppFTP As Object, xlWb As Object, xlWs As Object
Set xlAppFTP = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWb = xlAppFTP.Workbooks.Open("X:\ANALYSIS\GHH.xlsm")
MyFullName = "X:\ANALYSIS\GHH" & format(Now(),"YYYYMMDD") & ".pdf"
xlWb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=0, FileName:=MyFullName, _
Quality:=1, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

For More Information. Go to this [Site](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28119179/MS-Access-VBA-to-convert-an-Excel-file-into-a-PDF-report.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. I need to have this pdf format in landscape orientation. I will ask in another question, please give me the answer.